How to install Python libraries in Azure Synapse Notebook Spark Cluster (pyspark)
I am facing a problem with Python libraries installation in Azure Synapse Notebook. I have tried installing two libraries, holidays and fugue using %pip... and !pip... I have tried even with .WHL files, but nothing is working. Cluster have not any restriction. The error is:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29776c5240>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/fugue/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29776c4ca0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/fugue/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29776c47c0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/fugue/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29776c7250>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/fugue/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f29776c4130>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/fugue/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fugue (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fugue
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Warning: PySpark kernel has been restarted to use updated packages.

Any thoughts about what is wrong?
Thanks in advanced
I have tried  %pip install fugue, and !pip install fugue, .whl files.

You can use the commands below:
pip install holidays

pip install fugue

Results:

References:

fugue 0.9.0
holidays 0.48

Also, learn more about managing libraries for Apache Spark pools in Azure Synapse Analytics.
Here is the Stack Overflow link to adding a custom Python library in Azure Synapse.
